# Retrofit implementation in Kotlin - Method Default Parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to implement this [getting started with Retrofit for Android](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) in **Kotlin**. I have made it as far as creating an instance of the `Retrofit` class but Kotlin dosen't seem to like it when I try to call the endpoint method in the interface **without** the callback parameter. Here is all the relevant code.

The Data Class:

```
data class GitHubRepo(val id:Int,val name:String)
```

The interface:

```
interface GitHubClient {
@GET("/users/{user}/repos")
fun reposForUser(@Path("user") user: String,callback: Callback<List<GitHubRepo>> )
}
```

Retrofit implementation:

```
    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()

    val builder = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

    val retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build()

    val client = retrofit.create(GitHubClient::class.java)

    val call =  client.reposForUser("fs-opensource") <-- Error - No value passed for parameter 'callback'
```

From the tutorial:

> You don’t pass your callback as the last parameter. You use the
>   client to get a call object. Once you’ve invoked .enqueue on the
>   created call object the request will be made by Retrofit

How do I implement this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reposForUser` method is expecting two arguments: a `String` and a `Callback`, but you're only providing the `String`:

```
 client.reposForUser("fs-opensource")
```

You can make your callback "optional" by doing this:

```
fun reposForUser(@Path("user") user: String, callback: Callback<List<GitHubRepo>>? )
```

I've added a question mark behind your callback's type in order to say: It's a **nullable** parameter. If you even want to say, that **no** callback is the **default**, also making the client call more convenient, I'd suggest you provide a default value for `callback`, like so:

```
fun reposForUser(@Path("user") user: String, callback: Callback<List<GitHubRepo>>? = null)
```

Be aware that you need to access `callback` in a safe way now, because it could be null. Read [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Comment: I know about the '?' nullable thing, but how did you make the 'callback' parameter optional in the second line of code ?

Comment: You mean here: "callback: Callback<List<GitHubRepo>>? = null" ? the callback is nullable and null by default, so you can call the method by just leaving out the second param